# How do you reference the view's window in Swift 3.x using Storyboards/Cocoa

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

with all the changes in Xcode and Swift, I can't figure out how to address the view's window in a stotyboard-driven project in the way I'm doing it in projects using XIBs. New to macOS programming so apologies in advance if this is basic stuff:

When using a storyboard, how do I change the view's window state using for instance:

```
window.titleVisibility = .hidden
window.setContentSize(size)
```

In an xib-driven project, I'm using

```
@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
```

but this doesn't seem to work the same way with storyboards. How do I do the same tihing using storyboards? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You can get a reference of your view window accessing its window property. Note that it can not be done inside view did load but you can create a window property for your view controller using a lazy initializer:

```
lazy var window: NSWindow! = self.view.window
```

And you can do your window customization inside the method viewWillAppear:

```
import Cocoa


class ViewController: NSViewController {

    lazy var window: NSWindow! = self.view.window

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        window.titleVisibility = .hidden
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do the above and then use window.titleVisibility = .hidden in viewDidLoad() the app crashes, but it works in viewWillAppear(). Is there a better place to have it?

Comment: `mainwindow.titleVisibility = .hidden` is wrong `window.titleVisibility = .hidden`

Comment: Did you try my code as it is ? What do you mean better place? inside viewDidLoad it can NOT be done. The `view.window` property will always return nil there

Comment: I renamed it in my app, sorry. Changed it back. It works, thanks again! Just wondering if viewWillAppear is a good place to have it :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
if let window = NSApplication.shared().mainWindow {
    window.titleVisibility = .hidden
}
```

Is this an ok way to do it?

Comment: just add `view.window?.titleVisibility = .hidden` inside viewWillAppear method.

Comment: What if your view window it is not the mainWindow?